# Best way to store time of day in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, mongoose, schema

I'm creating a schema in Mongoose, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to store a field representing the time of day ie 3:30, it does not need to be a fully qualified timestamp because the date is irrelevant.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question correctly without knowing how are you planning to use this date.

Comment: Ultimately I want to write a cron that reoccurs at a certain time of day every day, I want the use to be able to choose that.

Comment: I know this question is old, but if someone is planning to store time values to use with the `"node-cron"` NodeJS package, then your best bet is to store the values as numbers and then concat a cronjob string like so: `"0 " + num + "* * *"`.

Answer (score 12):

I'd suggest storing it either as seconds since midnight (as a `Number`) or as a padded numeric `String` stored in 24 hour format.

For example, `3:30PM`:

1. Seconds (stored as a number): `55800`
2. String: `"1530"`  (always must be 24 hour format with a leading numeric digit to have the same number of places, so `8:30AM` would be `"0830"`

Both can be sorted, indexed, queried by range. Both take approximately the same number of bytes. Since neither is very human friendly readable, you'd probably need to format them either way for display. It's really up to you which one would work better for your use.