# set only time in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to set only time in mongoose schema ?
like we can do in `sequelize schema`

```
 startTime: DataTypes.TIME,
    endTime: DataTypes.TIME
```

is their any way in mongoose to set time in mongoose schema??

Answer (score 2):

It's simple Date and nothing else like this --> `startTime : Date`

Here is the documentation for all available data types for mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

In case you only require the time of the date you can use a getters to achieve that: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html

Comment: i want only time .. and Date give whole time stamp @slowdeath007

Comment: You still use the Date datatype and use getters to take only the time: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html

Answer (score 0):

I've tried achieving the same thing before but failed.

The best solution that was I able to come up with was to just add the time during the insert to the database and not when creating the schema.

This way you can use `datetime.toLocaleTimeString();` or moment.js to just add the time without the date etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no mongoose schema type to store a time like you can do in SQL.

I have stored a time as a Date in one of my project, keeping just the time part of that date. It works more or less.
And maybe MongoDB `$hour` and `$minute` aggregation can help.
But it is not a very elegant solution.

Another possibility is to store your time as separate Number (hours, minutes, seconds).

Best method I found so far is to store it as a String, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475538/5156280).

Maybe you can go further into this idea and create your own [custom](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html) schema Time type.